# How to make HTTP requests from different URLs stored in a text file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm new to Node. I have a txt file with three different URLs, one on each line. I want to read each line, axios.get that URL, and then write the content of each response to a different txt file and name that file the name of the website.

For example, `urls.txt` currently has:

```
https://google.com
https://facebook.com
https://twitter.com
```

I want to be able to run `node app.js urls.txt` and have three files created for me with the names `google.txt`, `facebook.txt`, and `twitter.txt`, and inside each file is the response.data for each call.

Right now I have it working, but only if there is a single URL in the txt file. It also writes the response to a file I already created `temp.txt`.

**app.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const process = require('process');
const axios = require('axios');


async function webCat(url) {
  let resp = await axios.get(url);
  fs.writeFile('temp.txt', resp.data, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`An error occured. , ${err}`);
      process.exit(1);
    }
});
}


fs.readFile('urls.txt', 'utf8', function (err, url) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  webCat(url);
});
```

How can I change this so that I can handle different URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to split URLs in the file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const process = require('process');
const axios = require('axios');


async function webCat(url) {
  let resp = await axios.get(url);
  const domain = url.split(/[/.]/)[2];
  fs.writeFile(`${domain}.txt`, resp.data, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`An error occured. , ${err}`);
      process.exit(1);
    }
});
}


fs.readFile('urls.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  const urls = data.split('\n');
  urls.forEach(url => webCat(url));
});
```